# Shiro - How to efficiently select all resources a user has permission for?

Tags: grails, shiro

I have implemented a service where user can upload files (here referred to as services) to analyze them. Each registered user has only access to his uploaded files.

So, after uploading a file I grant the user a wildcard permission for that file:

```
def currentUser = SecurityUtils.subject

if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    def user = User.findByUsername(currentUser.principal)
    user.addToPermissions("service:*:$serviceId")
    user.save()
}
```

When accessing a file, I check if the currently logged in user has the permission to open that file:

```
SecurityUtils.subject.checkPermission("service:*:$id")
```

This seems to work all fine but now I want to give the logged in user a way to list all his uploaded files. For that, I get the user, take all his permissions, extract the IDs and then search for the files:

```
    def user = User.findByUsername(SecurityUtils.subject.principal)
    def serviceIds = user.permissions.collect { it.split(':').last().toLong() }

    [services: Service.findAllByIdInList(serviceIds)]
```

While this works, it seems horribly inefficient. What would be a better way to implement this? Maybe create a relation between the user and the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could as you said create a relation between `User` and `Service` (1 -> M) making it easier to run a query for the `Service` objects for that `User`.  My thinking of this is that it sounds like it fits within your domain model, after all, it sounds like there is a real relationship between the `User` and the `Service` as the `Service` does in fact belong to the `User`.  Permissions are still helpful for controlling who has access to the `Service` whilst that one `User` remains the owner of the `Service`

```
[services: Service.findAllByUser(User.findByUsername(SecurityUtils.subject.principal))]
```

It might not make it any more efficient but it is a cleaner solution

Comment: In addition, I would not use the shiro permissions to check if the user is allowed to access the file. If he is really only allowed to see his own files, it is easier to check the ownership...

Comment: @Ralf providing there is no chance in the future that even some files may be made public - then yes I would agree

Comment: how will you mark files as public? If it is with a flag, you can easily check for something like `if isOwner || isPublic`. With your concept, you woul dhave to assign _every_ user the right permission for public files - even for users which will register in the future...